# How do I go about this form validation?

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have a form consisting of the following elements:

- First Name
- Last Name
- User ID
- Reference Number
- Asset Tag
- From Date
- To Date

I'm trying to apply validation on my form such that the form will `enable` the submit button when the following rules are satisfied.

- There must always be a from date, and to date.
- There must be at least one of the following

  - A last name **and** firstname
  - A user ID
  - A reference number
  - An asset tag

I'm built my form with `formGroup` like so:

```
this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
    criteria: this.fb.group({
        name: this.fb.group({
            firstName: [{ value: null, disabled: false }, [
                Validators.pattern(new RegExp('[A-Za-z]'))
            ]],
            lastName: [{ value: null, disabled: false }, [
                Validators.pattern(new RegExp('[A-Za-z]'))
            ]],
        }, { validator: atLeastOneName }),
        userId: [{ value: null, disabled: false }, [
            Validators.minLength(8),
            Validators.maxLength(8)
        ]],
        refNumber: [{ value: null, disabled: false }, [
            Validators.minLength(7),
            Validators.maxLength(7)
        ]],
        assetTag: [{ value: null, disabled: false }, [
            Validators.minLength(9),
            Validators.maxLength(9)
        ]],
    }, { validator: atLeastOne }),
    fromDate: [moment().subtract(30, 'days').format('MM/DD/YYYY'), [
        Validators.required
    ]],
    toDate: [moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY'), [
        Validators.required
    ]]
}, { validator: hasValidDates });
```

My validators are as such

```
export function atLeastOne(form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors {
    const message = {
        'search': {
            'message': 'At least one field should be entered for the search'
        }
    };

    let hasValues = false;

    Object.keys(form.value).map(k => {
        if (form.value[k] !== '' && form.value[k] !== null) { hasValues = true; }
    });

    console.log('hasValues: ', hasValues);

    return hasValues ? null : message;
}

export function atLeastOneName(form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors {
    const message = {
        'search': {
            'message': 'At least one name must be present for the search'
        }
    };

    let hasNames = false;

    let firstName = form.value['firstName'],
        lastName = form.value['lastName'];

    if (firstName && lastName) {
        hasNames = true;
    } else if (!firstName && !lastName) {
        hasNames = true;
    } else {
        hasNames = false;
    }

    console.log('hasNames: ', hasNames);

    return hasNames ? null : message;
}

export function hasValidDates(form: FormGroup): ValidationErrors {
    const message = {
        'search': {
            'message': 'Your input dates are invalid, please double check them.'
        }
    };

    let validDates = false;

    let fromDate = form.controls['fromDate'],
        toDate = form.controls['toDate'];

    if (new Date(fromDate.value) <= new Date(toDate.value)) {
        validDates = true;
    }

    let momentFromDate = moment(fromDate.value),
        momentToDate = moment(toDate.value);
    if (momentFromDate.diff(momentToDate, 'months') > 6) {
        validDates = false;
        message.search.message = 'Please restrict your input dates to less than a 6 month period.';
    }

    return validDates ? null : message;
}
```

However; with this current structure, the form is enabled when the page is loaded. Which is not desired because there are *no* values for first name, last name, user id, ref number, or asset tag. I feel there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: have you try ngOnInit () {
    this.searchForm.updateValueAndValidity();
} ?

Comment: No but I just added that and it didn't seem to make a difference. I believe my validators are conflicting with one and other. My `atLeastOne` validator is saying that the `form.value['name']` has values because it is an object when in fact it does not because the fields themselves are emtpy.

Comment: If I add `&& k !== 'name'` to my `atLeastOne` validator that seems to do the trick with regards to making sure the form isn't valid *too soon* but it blocks the validity if I enter valid entries in the `names` form group.

Comment: then try if (form.value[k] !== '' && form.value[k] !== null && !form.invalid) in atLeastOne validator

Comment: Very close but again the form is now valid on load, with no inputs (not desired), valid once I start typing input (desired), valid after I remove inputs from the form (not desired).